# using scatter matrix plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-matrix

jumping from R to python since org. wants very work to be done in python :(. struggling what seems to be a very basic task.
i have a dataframe 25*25 with rows as observations and columns as different atttributes. I want to plot these 25 columns scatter plot...seems like a very simple task. but unfortunately unable to do so

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(welldat, alpha=0.2,grid=True)
```

program giving following error -

```
ValueError: Number of columns must be > 0, not 0

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: have you verified that `welldat` is definitely a DataFrame? It might also be worth checking the dtype of your columns

Comment: yes, welldat is a dataframe 25*25 and columns are all "object" dtype.....